# Как сохранить цвет кнопки при перезагрузке приложение в java окна?

Tags: java, jdk11

`private JButton button=new JButton("button");`

`button.addActionListener(new Ac());`

`private class Ac implements ActionListener{ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){`

`Object source = e.getSource();`

`if (((Component)source).getBackground().equals(Color.red)){`
`((Component)source).setBackground(null);`
`} else { ((Component)source).setBackground(Color.red);`

`} }`

// Когда приложение снова запустится нужно чтобы вывелся последний цвет кнопки который был нажат.

Comment: какую цель вы преследуете, задавая полностью идентичные вопросы?

Comment: просто так ............

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сохранить цвет кнопки при перезагрузке в java приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)